# Create alerts in django application

Tags: python, django

I have  model that contains a date of expiry. The field looks like this:

passport_date_of_expiry = TodayOrLaterDateField ('Date of Expiry',)

This field is shown in the list display in the admin. What i would like to be accomplished is such that when the date of expiry is 6months or less to the expiry date, the item is highlighted with a red line in the list display of the admin. OR. Make the system send an email as an alert when this even occurs. How can i be able to achieve this with ease. There is already a big amount of data in the database and this is a feature i would like to add to this system.

Comment: This isn't a programming question as much as a requirement.

Comment: you can put condition in your view: if passport expire then send notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To highlight in admin you can use something like following (got this from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/):

```python
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def colored_name(self):
        if datetime.datetime.now() >= self.expiry_date:
            return '<span style="color: red;">%s %s</span>' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    colored_name.allow_tags = True

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('colored_name', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

This will highlight onlye one collumn in admin interface but this can be noticed.

To alert you should create management command and run it from cron.

project/app/management/commands/check_expired.py:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.core import management
from django.core.mail import mail_admins


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
        expired_items = Model.objects.filter(expiry_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
        message = some_message_formatter(expired_items)

        mail_admins(subject='Alerts on my Project!', message=message)
```

cron:

```cron
8 3 */15 * * cd /path/to/project && echo 'Activate virtual env if needed' && PYTHONPATH='Additional_python_path' DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_project.settings django-admin.py check_expired
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the route of highlighting the item in the list display of the admin, you'll need to override the admin/change_list_results.html template.  The snippet from that file looks like this:

```
{% for result in results %}
{% if result.form.non_field_errors %}
<tr><td colspan="{{ result|length }}">{{ result.form.non_field_errors }}</td></tr>
{% endif %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
    {% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}   
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You might try adding code to inspect if the result item has the attribute you're looking for and use a different class than row1 or row2. Just remember this is a file used for all objects in the admin.

For sending emails, you could write a standalone script to be called by cron.  Make sure to add the path of your virtualenv to sys.path and set os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] to your project settings.  After that it should be an easy query to find the expired objects and send mail using django.core.mail.MailMessage.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/

Comment: thanks ryan. I will work on it. Thanks for the help.